# 'Collection' object is not callable when trying to count the number of documents in that collection

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, typeerror

I am trying to store the configuration data which is done by server admins via the commands in MongoDB

Here I am trying to check whether the server admin did configure the setting or not

```
        query = {"_id": ctx.guild.id}
        if (self.bot.config_collection.count_documents(query) == 0):
            try:
                post = {"_id": ctx.guild.id, "todo_channel": int(
                    channel)}
                self.bot.config_collection.insert_one(post)
                embedSucess = discord.Embed(
                    description='The configuration for `sd!todo` command is done',
                    color=discord.Color.from_rgb(230, 242, 251))
                await ctx.send(embed=embedSucess)
            except ValueError:
                embedError = discord.Embed(
                    description='Use channel IDs as the arguments',
                    color=discord.Color.from_rgb(221, 107, 206))
                await ctx.send(embed=embedError)
```

But I am facing this error

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'count_documents' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

The above given python code is responsible for the error, but I don't understand what went wrong with that piece of code

Comment: [These](https://imgur.com/AoZMryR.png) are the collections in my database

Comment: `self.bot.config_collection` should be referring to a _collection_. And, you need to make sure of it. Then you can run the method `count_documents` method on it.

Comment: @prasad_ `self.bot.config_collection` is referring to a collection.